# What's the Difference Between CS.SE and CSTheory.SE?

Tags: discussion

We have these two sites:

- https://cs.stackexchange.com/
- http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

I just cannot discern if there is a meaningful difference between the two sites. From a random sample of questions on the front page, it seems as if there is an enormous overlap in their content. Additionally, neither site has a large number of questions: so, should the two sites be merged?

Comment: Well, one is beta, and one isn't, so if the beta site can't distinguish itself from a graduated site then it simply won't be graduated.

Comment: @Servy, what will happen then if ever CS.SE is closed? All topics will be moved to CSTheory.SE?

Comment: @Hibou57 That's something that would be decided on a case by case basis.  That is one option though, yes.

Comment: I mainly hope the content won't go to a trash‑bin.